# Темная тема yamaps3

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

new YMapDefaultSchemeLayer({theme: 'dark'})

с недавних пор стал игнорироваться prop с темой. Включается только светлая. В чем может быть дело?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Вопросы про нерабочие параметры API лучше сразу направлять через поддержку к разработчикам. В этом случае к Яндексу.

Пока же можно задавать тёмную тему через карту:

```
ymaps3.ready.then(() => {
    const map = new ymaps3.YMap(document.getElementById('map'), {
        location: {center: [37.723202, 55.585051],zoom: 10},
        theme: 'dark'
    })
    map.addChild(new ymaps3.YMapDefaultSchemeLayer()); 
});
```

Comment: сутки буквально выдавало светлую тему на theme: 'dark'. Я уже подумал ее сделали частью платной кастомизации. Сейчас все норм

Comment: Да. Но может и альтернативный способ включить тёмную тему кому пригодится. =)